# What software can I use to 3d model and simulate my robot?

Tags: simulation, simulator, humanoid, 3d-model

I would like to know if there is any software that I can 3d model my robot and insert that model into some sort of simulation software where I can run AI related code(in python). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on much "standards" is your robot and how much coding of the simulator you want to code.

If you don't want to simulate contact the easiest way is to write down your own simulator in you favorite language, based on the underlying mathematical model of your robot. If you have access to matlab the simmechanics toolbox, can be interesting because the toolbox derive the dynamical model on its own, but it is poorly documented (and expensive).

If you have a "standard robots" you can look at V-REP or gazebo, which are working standalone or in combination with ROS. Some robots models are already coded or can be easily generated. ROS is compatible with python.
You can also have a look at the MORSE simulator, which has been developed for academia.

I am pretty sure that my list is non-exhaustive, but it should provide you some starting points.

Comment: I created a video where I show how to get the moving graphics of a mechanical arm
https://youtu.be/crJXUlzJ918

Answer (score 0):

For 3D modelling go with a Solidworks and for Simulation use Matlab.These links might help you:

1- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nSafEJlySs&feature=youtu.be

2- [MATLAB 3D Simulation with SOLIDWORKS model](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/matlab-3d-simulation-with-solidworks-model?rq=1)